# How to delete aws-lambdas based on their tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-lambda

I have few lambdas created by automation using Ansible.

`- lambda:
     name: 'NAME'
     state: present
     zip_file: 'index.js.zip'
     tags:
       createdBy: 'ansible'`

And few more lambdas which are created manually.

I would like to delete all lambdas which are created by "Ansible", so I added "tag" attribute to all the automated lambdas.

I know, we can delete lambda if we have its name, but I would like to get all lambdas and filter the lambda which has `tags['createdBy']='ansible`.

`lambda_facts` are a way to get all lambda configuration, but it doesn't give me tag details.

How do I delete lambdas by filtering tags ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to get all your functions with help of [lambda.listFunctions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listFunctions-property) and run [lambda.listTags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listTags-property) for each Lambda and build your own array with all functions which includes `ansible` as a tag.

In the end iterate over this array and call [lambda.deleteFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#deleteFunction-property) for each entry.

(I dont know which language you prefer. All my examples are using the JavaScript SDK)

Comment: I am not using JavaScript SDK, I am doing this automation by Ansible. Thats where the problem is, not able to figure out how to get all functions information which includes tags.